# How to set running python as pyhton3.6 in ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

While installing a project requirement file (`pip install -r requirements.txt`) terminal is giving this error:

```
css-html-js-minify requires Python '>=3.6' but the running Python is 2.7.12
```

I think the issue is due to the library “css-html-js-minify” which requires a Python version >= 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pip3`.

> Note that on some Linux distributions including Ubuntu and Fedora the pip command is meant for Python 2, while the pip3 command is meant for Python 3.

[Installing Python on Linux](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/#setuptools-pip).